# How to replace text wrapped by tabs using regular expression and Sublime Text?

Tags: regex, replace, find, sublimetext3

I have the following pattern:

```
SomeText    SomeText    SomeText
SomeProp    SomeProp    SomeProp
Property    Property    Property
```

Each word are separated by a tab `\t`.

I need to replace the second/middle word by `prefix + middle word + suffix`.

I use this regex to select the second word:

```
\t(\w)*\t
```

But when I try to replace it:

```
\t prefix\1suffix \t
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're repeating the capture group; only the last word character will be captured. Place the operator inside of the group construct to quantify the `\w` token instead of the group.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the **Search and Replace**, enable *Regular Expression* if you haven't ..

```
Find What: \t(\w+)\t
Replace With: \tprefix\1suffix\t
```